# Flex items with same height in the same column with Flexbox-direction column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, media-queries

I am facing issues in making a responsive web page. Here are some of the details:

Here is my HTML code and CSS code: -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css"
        integrity="sha512-5A8nwdMOWrSz20fDsjczgUidUBR8liPYU+WymTZP1lmY9G6Oc7HlZv156XqnsgNUzTyMefFTcsFH/tnJE/+xBg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        html,
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: hsl(210, 46%, 95%);
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .article {
            height: 280px;
            max-width: 700px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .article-preview {
            height: 280px;
            width: 290px;
            background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1591843336309-cbf414ad7978?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80g');
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: top center;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
            flex: 1;
        }

        .article-info {
            flex: 1.19;
            background: #ffff;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
            padding-left: 40px;
            padding-right: 35px;
            padding-top: 25px;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .article-info h1 {
            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 1.5;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        .article-info p {
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 1.5;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding-right: 8px;
        }

        i.fa.fa-apple {
            background: #f0f0f0;
            margin-right: 8px;
            border-radius: 100px;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 40px;
        }

        .article-author {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .article-author .author-info {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .article-author .author-info span {
            font-size: 13px;
        }

        .article-author .author-info .author-name {
            font-weight: 700;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
        }

        .article-author .author-info .date {
            font-weight: 500;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="article">
            <div class="article-preview"></div>
            <div class="article-info">
                <h1>
                    Have the courage to follow your heart and intuition.
                </h1>
                <p>
                    Steve Jobs was is one of the most respected entrepreneurs and inventors of his time. In 1976 he
                    founded Apple together with his friend Steve Wozniak. They created their first computer, the Apple
                    I, in the garage of Jobs’ parents.
                </p>
                <div class="article-author">
                    <i class="fa fa-apple" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <div class="author-info">
                        <span class="author-name">Steven Paul Jobs</span>
                        <span class="date">28 Jun 2020</span>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

I  want the flexbox item with image having the class .article-preview to move in the upper direction, and the other flexbox item with item information having the class .article-info to move in the bottom of previous one.

To make this page responsive for a maximum browser width of 763px , I've added the @media query with the following changes: -

```
@media (max-width: 763px) {
            .article {
                height: 70%;
                width: 290px;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;

                border: 3px dotted red;
            }

            .article > * {
                flex: 1;
                height: 290px;
                width: 290px;

                border: 1px solid darkmagenta;
            }
            
        }
```

But, it has just messed thing up. I've set the hight attribute for both the children of main container for the content, but still their height is different.
The content is the .article-info div container is also getting leaked / moving outside this container.

I want to 1) set their direction column, 2) both the flex items to have the same size, 3) the content should not flow outside, but remain inside its container, and 4) we change the browser size (smaller or larger), instead of moving outside, it should change its size etc within its container, while maintaining its layout.

It is important to mention that I am a novice developer and am learning things. Kindly suggest me where I am getting wrong and how I can achieve the responsiveness with the aims mentioned.

PS: It is important to mention that I need to implement the solution using HTML and CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code.

on test I've done when vertical, article-info grow to display the content which is normal (and 305px instead of 290px).

You have several ways to solve but it's much more a question of design you want.

1. let the card container grow to fit the content.

- if you leave the image at a fix size, upper part won't have same height as lower part
- if you want same height, your image background-size to cover to fill, and you won't have the whole image

2. try to fit the article-info inside the actual height

- first you can play with the padding in @media. Test several smaller values. If you know text will always be from this size to this size, you can perhaps find values which work.
- you can play with clamp, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp. It's still test and try solution. If you have very very long info, it'll still break design

3. cut text in info.

- pure css, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow
- if you want to use javascript, see here https://github.com/pierfarrugia/text_overflow